# Regex for a Football table

Tags: python, regex

I have a football table in the free text format as:

```
   1  Cibalia Vinkovci          0  30  21   5   4  67  24   43   68 [promoted]
   2  Vihor Jelisavac           0  30  16   6   8  44  29   15   54
   3  Cepin                     0  30  14   7   9  49  29   20   49
   4  Belisce                   0  30  14   6  10  53  39   14   48
   5  Mladost Zdralovi          0  30  13   8   9  48  35   13   47 [moved to group "North"]   
   6  Slavonija Pozega          0  30  12   7  11  45  40    5   43
   7  Marsonia Slavonski Brod   0  30  12   6  12  38  40   -2   42
   8  Zrinski Jurjevac          0  30  11   8  11  35  35    0   41
  14  Vukovar 1991              0  30   8   7  15  29  52  -23   31
```

I stuggle to create a regex which will work for optional numbers and multiple space delimited words.
Whatever I create tends to include numbers following a club name or fails in some other way.

Example:

This is probably closest I managed to get. Regex works fine as long as I have at most two words and no numbers.
`(\d+)\s+([A-Za-z\s]+)(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)`
This works for all lines but 7 and 14.

When I add numbers to the 2nd group regex start overflowing into integers in the table:
`(\d+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)`

Edit:
Tim asked to point out what is expected outcome:
Example:

`match = [ '14','Vukovar 1991','0','30','8','7','15','29','52','-23','31' ]`

Comment: You should at least highlight what data you are trying to extract from the one line sample.

Comment: A regex doesn't look like the right tool here…

Comment: I've managed to use this regex for a slightly different text and it worked just fine. That made me think I can try using regex:
Example of the text:
3.Osijek                       36  18  8 10  61-36  62
regex that worked:
(\d+)\.([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)-(\d+)\s+(\d+)

Comment: I think a `re.split(r'\s+', line)` would make more sense than a regex. Just take the results of that and remove the last column if necessary. Something like `desired_rows = [re.split(r'\s+', line) for line in text]; desired_rows = [row if isinstance(row[-1], int) else row[:-1]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following regex:

```py
"(\d+)\s{2}([A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(-?\d+)\s+(\d+)(?:\s+\[(.+)\])?"gm
```

See demo in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ueTSw2/1)

Python code:

```py
import re

regex = r"(\d+)\s{2}([A-Za-z]+(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(-?\d+)\s+(\d+)(?:\s+\[(.+)\])?"

test_str = ("1  Cibalia Vinkovci          0  30  21   5   4  67  24   43   68 [promoted]\n"
    "2  Vihor Jelisavac           0  30  16   6   8  44  29   15   54\n"
    "3  Cepin                     0  30  14   7   9  49  29   20   49\n"
    "4  Belisce                   0  30  14   6  10  53  39   14   48\n"
    "5  Mladost Zdralovi          0  30  13   8   9  48  35   13   47 [moved to group \"North\"]   \n"
    "6  Slavonija Pozega          0  30  12   7  11  45  40    5   43\n"
    "7  Marsonia Slavonski Brod   0  30  12   6  12  38  40   -2   42\n"
    "8  Zrinski Jurjevac          0  30  11   8  11  35  35    0   41\n"
    "14  Vukovar 1991              0  30   8   7  15  29  52  -23   31\n")

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
```